# InnoSetup - Create Windows Update

Tags: windows, inno-setup, updates

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to create a Windows Update through InnoSetup.

I have to create a RDP8.0 installation package for Windows7.

The problem is that before I can proceed to install RDP8 I have to install a Windows7 Update.

I would like to know if it possible to:

Install DTLS Update (it requires reboot when it finish)
Reboot
CONTINUE SETUP and Install RDP8
Reboot

Thanks in Advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

To install any Windows Update package, you can call wusa,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934307

Since you are using Inno Setup, you can include the update package in your installer, and write pascal scripts to extract the package and call wusa for installation.

Reboot can be suppressed during installation by using `/norestart`, and only when your app has fully installed you prompt the user to reboot the machine.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the answer.
I'm not able to use PASCAL Scripts.
I knew the norestart option, but i thought that he had to reboot before it could install RDP8.
I have tryied now manually (to install prereq updates NO reboot) and install RDP 8 and worked, so I guess I had only to add /norestart to the packages.
Thanks for the help :-)